# How to parse DWORDs in JNA

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I'm trying to query the status of a Windows service in Java using JNA.  I'm using the following Windows API function:

```
QuerySerivceStatusEx( SC_HANDLE hService, SC_STATUS_TYPE InfoLevel, LPBYTE lpBuffer, DWORD cbBufSize, LPDWORD pcbBytesNeeded)
```

Inside the `LPBYTE lpBuffer` is a pointer to a structure.  And inside the structure it stores the current state as a `DWORD`.  According to JNA documentation `DWORDs` map into `ints` in Java, and according to WinSvc.h the `DWORD` associated with running is `0x00000004` so in my code I defined a final int with value `0x00000004` like

```
public static final int SERVICE_RUNNING = 0x00000004
```

When I run the code and the service I'm querying is running I'm getting back a value of `16` which isn't defined at all in WinSvc.h.  Is there some kind of translation I'm missing?

EDIT: To clairfy here are all the states a service can be in and their associated values:

```
   public static final int SERVICE_STOPPED            = 0x00000001;
   public static final int SERVICE_START_PENDING      = 0x00000002;
   public static final int SERVICE_STOP_PENDING       = 0x00000003;
   public static final int SERVICE_RUNNING            = 0x00000004;
   public static final int SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING   = 0x00000005;
   public static final int SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING      = 0x00000006;
   public static final int SERVICE_PAUSED             = 0x00000007;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up figuring out my problem.  16 was being returned regardless of whether the service was started or stopped.  As it turns out I didn't have the structure being returned, [SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), defined in the same order that it is defined in the native library.  I was unaware this needed to be done, but you need to define your structures in the same order that they are in in the native code.

Answer (score 0):

Values like that are often many flag values or'ed together. e.g., to indicate both a `4` and a `2` flag, you would get `4 | 2` or `6`. You could then figure out which flags are set by anding together the result (`6`) with each of the flags and seeing if it's true (`6 & 4` or `6 & 2` would be true, but `6 & 1` would not be, so you know flags `4` and `2` are set but not `1`).

That being said, 16 would be a basic value (it's a power of 2), so I'm unsure.

Comment: I don't think it makes since in this case.  The values for the states are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 which wouldn't make that work.  I'll edit the question to clarify

Comment: what structure is being returned? can you link to the winapi docs?